# Alternative to test-path, using credential, to hosts on a different domain, with wildcard in folder path

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to copy a file to a specific folder on one of n hosts (hostA, hostB etc.), but i don't know the full path of the folder.

If I don't use a credential (which I have to do) I can e.g.

```
test-path -path \\hostA\d$\*\targetFolder ...and hit D:\blah\targetFolder
```

I could use the credential with new-psdrive, but then I can't map to a wildcarded path. I could also invoke-command, but then I'd have to work out a way to get the file from the sourceHost...

This is for a TFS/AzureDevops pipe.

Comment: you can map it with new-psdrive with parameter `-persist` it indicates that this cmdlet creates a Windows mapped network drive. The Persist parameter is only available on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive), map a (non-persistent, PS-only) drive  to the admin share `\\hostA\d$` itself, and then use that drive for wildcard-based path testing:

```
# Define a PS-only RemoteD: drive that maps to \\hostA\d$,
# using the specified credentials.
New-PSDrive RemoteD FileSystem \\hostA\d$ -Credential (Get-Credential)

# Use paths based on RemoteD: for wildcard-based testing.
Test-Path RemoteD:\*\targetFolder
```